# How to run service in background always even app is force closed

Tags: android, android-studio, service

I am working on an application which need to show toast constantly.
I've a service to show the toast every 15 seconds.
I've given the return START_STICKY from onStartCommand().
when the app is in background it is working fine and when the app is force closed by the user the service is getting stopped,the service fails to execute.

Comment: Man, this would be handy for virus authors...